# UIPickerView in Detailview with .PLIST

Tags: iphone, uitableview, plist, uipickerview

I've searched the web + stackoverflow for a solution.

I've an UITableView with information from a .plist file. The plist file have childs. Like the image.

[plist http://www.afbeeldingenuploaden.nl/uploads/648899Schermafbeelding%202011-06-12%20om%2009.50.28.png](http://www.afbeeldingenuploaden.nl/uploads/648899Schermafbeelding%202011-06-12%20om%2009.50.28.png)

When i go to DetailView it will display information out of an UIPickerView that's included in the view. I want to display information from the child in the pickerview, the last level. Like the image.

[plist1 http://www.afbeeldingenuploaden.nl/uploads/740501Schermafbeelding%202011-06-12%20om%2012.03.40.png](http://www.afbeeldingenuploaden.nl/uploads/740501Schermafbeelding%202011-06-12%20om%2012.03.40.png)

The problem is that i can't reach the last level from the plist in the UIPickerview with my code.

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [tableDataSource objectAtIndex:row];
    return [dictionary objectForKey:@"days"];
}
```

I use in my tableview for the detailview to reach the last level of the plist.

```
NSString currentLevel
```

Can anyone help me out with this, i'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

As I read the plist, it has an array of dictionaries first of which has a dictionary as one of its values at the second array level. Based on that, your method should be,

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [tableDataSource objectAtIndex:row];

    return [[dictionary objectForKey:@"New item"] objectForKey:@"days"];
}
```

This will work for the plist in the image. However if more members are added they should adhere to the same structure.

Comment: How do you get `tableDataSource`?

Comment: I posted as an answer related in this topic.

Comment: Can you also post `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. I just need to know how you are filling the rows using `tableDataSource`.

Comment: I've posted also the code for didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method. There you can see how I get to the last level of my .plist in the Detailview to get the strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

NSString *Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *DataPath = [Path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Diyet.plist"];

NSDictionary *tempDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:DataPath];
self.data = tempDict;
[tempDict release];

NSArray *tempArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
self.tableDataSource = tempArray;
[tempArray release];

self.tableDataSource = [data objectForKey:@"Bitki"];

pickerView.delegate = self;
pickerView.dataSource = self;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

// Configure the cell.

cell.textLabel.text = [[tableDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];

tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;

return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


NSDictionary *dictionary = [tableDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSArray *modelle = [dictionary objectForKey:@"DETAIL"];
if([modelle count] == 0) {

    DetailController *dvController = [[DetailController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];


    dvController.names.text = [dictionary objectForKey:@"name"];

} else {

    BootViewController *rvController = [[BootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BootViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    rvController.currentLevel += 1;

    rvController.currentTitle = [dictionary objectForKey:@"name"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:rvController animated:YES];

    rvController.tableDataSource = modelle;

    [rvController release];
}
}
```